# How to insert unique records from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a sample table `table1`:

```
id     transaction_number     net_amount      category      type
1      100000                  2000            A            ZA
2      100001                  4000            A            ZA
3      100002                  6000            B            ZB
```

I've a sample table `table2`:

```
id     transaction_number      net_amount      category        type
1      100002                  6000               B             ZB
```

How do I insert unique records that are not in `table2`, but present in `table1`?

Desired result:

```
id    transaction_number       net_amount     category        type
1      100002                   6000              B           ZB
2      100000                   2000              A           ZA
3      100001                   4000              A           ZB
```

Comment: So you mean copy from table1 to table2 only those rows not in table2? According to which column (which column(s) define a row as being "already there")?

Comment: yes and according to transaction_number column.

Comment: What is your schema for `table1` and `table2`? Is `id` a primary key and auto_increment?

Comment: Yes, Im sorry I didn't mention in the description.

Comment: How are you defining "unique records"?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table2 ( transaction_number, net_amount, category, type )
(
  /* Rows in table1 that don't exist in table2: */
  SELECT ( table1.transaction_number, table1.net_amount, table1.category, table1.type )
  FROM table1
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON ( table1.transaction_number = table2.transaction_number )
  WHERE table2.transaction_number IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to duplicate transaction numbers in `table2`, then create a unique index or constraint on that column (or the columns you want to be unique).  Let the database handle the integrity of the data:

```
alter table table2 add constraint unq_table2_transaction_number
    unique (transaction_number);
```

Then use `on duplicate key update` with a dummy update:

```
insert into table2 (transaction_number, net_amount, category, type)
    select transaction_number, net_amount, category, type
    from table1
    on duplicate key update transaction_number = values(transaction_number);
```

Why do I recommend this approach?  First, it is thread-safe, so it works even when multiple queries are modifying the database at the same time.  Second, it puts the database in charge of data integrity, so the transactions will be unique *regardless of how they are changed*.

Note that the most recent versions of MySQL have deprecated this syntax in favor of the (standard) `on conflict` clause.  The functionality is similar, but I don't think those versions are widespread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO table2 (transaction_number,net_amount,category,type)
(SELECT transaction_number,net_amount,category,type from table1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
net_amount=VALUES(net_amount),category=VALUES(category),type=VALUES(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usw `not exists` as follows:

```
Insert into table2
Select t1.*
  From table1 t1
 Where not exists 
       (Select 1 from table2 t2
         Where t1.transaction_number = t2.transaction_number)
```